# Address length requirements

Tags: tangle, address

If one sends a 0-value transaction to an address with less than 90 chars [A-Z9], I noticed that thetangle.org appends the address with some random characters so that it consists of exactly 90 chars.

If you lookup https://thetangle.org/address/QPADAPGKZ9MTFRDDJXWTCKSMXNXOSECBWCLRIGBONSEGUBSRSHDWHRENIEIQJBBTVQJGBKLUZVMILPBJN it actually looks for tx at QPADAPGKZ9MTFRDDJXWTCKSMXNXOSECBWCLRIGBONSEGUBSRSHDWHRENIEIQJBBTVQJGBKLUZVMILPBJNNOKCNTQYX

I am wondering why thetangle.org does this? I assume that these transactions are just stored with the orginal address. Am I right? What are the actual requirements for a valid address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a valid address is always exactly 81 chars [A-Z9]. Most tools interacting with human users append a 9 chars length checksum to the address.

When this checksum is present, it's possible for a tool to check that a copy/paste typo didn't append at some point.

So thetangle.org don't append *random* chars to an address of 81 chars, it only appends the checksum.

Comment: Why is exactly 81 chars?  iota doc says can be 81, 162, 243 and  243 is advised to use?   https://docs.iota.org/introduction/iota-token/seeds-private-keys-accounts